# Why Google spreadsheets API stops applying formatting after entering certain amount of data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have an app, which manages Google drive structure and updates existing Google sheets. On all of those Sheets documents, I came across strange behaviour. Once I add some amount of data (at around 80-100 entered rows), the spreadsheet stops applying some formatting over data.

App is C# / .NET Standard (4.7.2), using [Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/) and GoogleSheetsApi-V4 as endpoint.

Application creates and send [batch update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) which contains both data and formatting (styles). Batch update is specific request as it is transactional - if any of the sub-requests will not be applied (e.g. request is not parsed via Google's server), whole request will not be applied (meaning all sub-requests get dropped).

I'm aware of [request-count limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) and I'm not hitting those. This behaviour occurrs on all tested files (around 50 in total) - first 80-100 rows are formatted without issues, the rest has problems.

Reply from the Google's API (after batch update request) is empty and doesn't report any error.

For the formatting I'm using `batchRequest` with several `requests`. I'm including them in the order as they are send and applied:

- `UpdateCells` with `CellData.UserEnteredValue`
- `MergeCells`
- `UpdateCells` with `CellData.UserEnteredFormat`
- `UpdateBorders`
- `RepeatCell`
- ...

---

**Does Google spreadsheets API have some limits for formatting? What might be the cause that formatting is lost at this part? Is there something I should be aware about that might be limiting this behaviour?**

---

Screenshot of bad formatting at certain amount of data (e.g. WORD_WRAP, TEXT_ALIGNMENT is not set, but cells are still "bordered" and background color is set for the columns):

[image: Screenshot of formatting getting lost after reaching certain limit of data]

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the request body (JSON data) and the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry, originally I have provided wrong information - the formatting, which is not applied, is "last request" in the batch update. May this severely affect the result?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and goal, and that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From  `the formatting, which is not applied, is "last request" in the batch update.` in your comment.

  - You want to reflect `WRAP` of `wrapStrategy` to the column 3 of the rows from 3 to 96 using the method of batchUpdate of Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your request body, I thought that `range` might be not correct. For example, if you want to reflect `WRAP` of `wrapStrategy` as follows.

  - From 3 to 96 for rows.
  - Column 3.

Please modify `range` as follows.

#### Modified request body:

Please modify `repeatCell` of the last request in your request body as follows, and test it again.

```
{
  "repeatCell": {
    "cell": {
      "userEnteredFormat": {
        "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
        "verticalAlignment": "MIDDLE",
        "wrapStrategy": "WRAP"
      }
    },
    "fields": "userEnteredFormat.wrapStrategy,userEnteredFormat.verticalAlignment,userEnteredFormat.horizontalAlignment",
    "range": {
      "startRowIndex": 3,
      "endRowIndex": 96,
      "startColumnIndex": 3,
      "endColumnIndex": 4,
      "sheetId": ### <--- Please set sheet ID.
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- By the way, about 2nd request of `mergeCells` in your request body, in this case, I think that the situation is not changed. Because the single cell is used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)

Comment: Sorry for the time invested into it, issue is actually complete elsewhere.. Because styling I'm setting via request is not the one I'm looking up for fix. I've had all 50 files preformated with some template file... which unfortunately have issue with style and since 75+ row the style missing. I appreciate your time and sorry once more for wasting it. :(

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and also my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue from your replying. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to understand about it and think of the solution.

Comment: The issue is resolved. Problem is with my template "Google sheet", from which all the documents were created. This template had previously set styles (e.g. word-wrap, font, ...), but only for 0-75~ rows. When I send request (batch-update) with all the styles, they are merged with existing style. The problem is that my batch-update doesn't have the styles I wanted (like word-wrap, ..) and I was thinking something is wrong with request. Because it was all working for first 0-80 rows.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Thank you for replying and adding more information. I could understand that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it.